# Number of column in a two dimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

How do I determine which column in a double `ArrayList` has the same value in all rows? My `ArrayList` looks like the image below.

[image]

**Update:** Seems like there are many where were confused by the question. I should have asked in a more eloquent way.

I have a two dimensional `ArrayList` which consists of `ArrayLists`. I have a certain number of rows and columns in this two dimensional `ArrayList`. I would like to create a method that would return how many numbers of columns are in that `ArrayList`. That was what I meant in my original question. Now I know how to create this method as I got help from some of the answers below.

Comment: What do you mean by `number of column from a double ArrayList`. Quite unclear tome.

Comment: I don't know what is being unclear here.. I would like to get the number of columns from a double `ArrayList` like the one shown in the picture.

Comment: You should explain how you map the idea of a "row" and a "column" to an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have an ArrayList of ArrayLists, then you can do this to retrieve number of "columns":

```
list.get(0).size()
```

It means get the first ArrayList from list and get it's size.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you just have nested `ArrayList`s, and the number of rows is represented by the "top" `ArrayList` size, you can just get the size of the first nested one:

```
aList.get(0).size();
```

...assuming of course that `aList` is your top most `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have a

```
List<List<MyType>> listOfList = ...
```

and you want to know the size of the inner dimension?

```
int width = listOfList.get(0).size();
```

assuming all lists/rows are the same size/width.